# How to populate google heatmap LatLng by java arraylist in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, google-maps-api-3

When user give dates as input in jsp page, all the latitude & longitude gets filled in java arraylist.

My servlet with arraylist -

```
String startDate=request.getParameter("from");
String endDate=request.getParameter("to");
List<LocInfo> rList=new ArrayList<LocInfo>();
   try {
    rList=LocBO.retrieveAll(startDate,endDate);
    request.setAttribute("Map", rList);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestDispatcher rx=request.getRequestDispatcher("xyz.jsp");
    rx.forward(request, response);
    }
```

***How to pass arraylist rList to populate google map LatLng in xyz.jsp?***

```
 <script>

var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: getPoints(),
    map: map
  });
}

function getPoints() {
  return [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.751266, -122.403355)
  ];
}

    </script>
```

Is JSON the only solution? If yes, please provide code according to this servlet/jsp & map. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gmarkers = [];
    function addMarker(data, imageIcon) {
    if (data != undefined && data.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
        lat: data[i].Latitude,
        lng: data[i].Longitude
        },
        map: map,
        icon: image
        });
        gmarkers[data[i].Id] = marker;

    }
    }
    }

     function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: {lat: 63.2703467, lng: -6.9219481 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        });
        addMarker();

    }
```